# Bootstrap keep columns togheter without space

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have started building a website with bootstrap but have some problems.
Because of diffrent image heights columns don't stay next to each other but instead jump to new row. This creates alot of empty space inbetween.
So i would like everything to be togheter without any space.
Have tried float:left; position:absolute; clearing floating and even googling but not found a solution.

Here is jsfiddle link: [Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5752/)

My code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-12 one"></div>

    <div class="col col-sm-8 two"></div>

    <div class="col col-sm-2 three"></div>
    <div class="col col-sm-2 four"></div>

    <div class="col col-sm-4 five"></div>

    <div class="col col-sm-4 six"></div>

    <div class="col col-sm-4 seven"></div>

    <div class="col col-sm-4 eight"></div>
    <div class="col col-sm-4 nine"></div>


</div>    
</div>
```

I found masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) like 5min ago but wanted to see with you if there is anything easier. Want as litle code as possible to use.
How would/do you solve this problem ?

Comment: You can only have a maximum of 12 columns in one row, you have a total of 44.

Comment: You're using bootsrap classes, but then you completely hack them and bend them to do something totally different than what they were made for. Stop using bootstrap columns to make a wall. Either use a wall plugin (like Freewall or something), or do it in custom CSS. Oh, and instead of naming your elements "one", "two", you can select them using `.col:nth-child(1)`, `.col:nth-child(2)`.

Comment: @JeremyThille `nth-child` starts at 0.

Comment: No, surprisingly, nth-child starts at 1 :) https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap each row can have up to 12 columns when you use more than 12 columns they will wrap onto a new line.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible. You can't place that many divs side by side using Bootstrap Grids (cols). You could create your own css and adjust width as you please.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="one col"></div>
   <div class="two col"></div>
   <div class="three col"></div>
   <div class="four col"></div>
   <div class="five col"></div>
   <div class="six col"></div>
   <div class="seven col"></div>
   <div class="eight col"></div>
   <div class="nine col"></div>
</div>

.col {

float:left
}

.one, .three, .five, .seven, .nine {

background-color:red;

height:100px;

width:10%

}

.two, .four, .six, .eight {

background-color:blue;

height:100px;

width:12%

}
```

As I mentioned you would change colors, width and height as needed.